# Installing satchmo without ssh access

Tags: python, django, ssh, satchmo

I want to install satchmo in my virtual hosting, but they dont provide ssh access for it. I want to know if it is possible. As i can see, adding some Satchmo requirements(http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/svn/requirements.html) to pythonpath in my .fcgi file seems to be working, but some requirements like pycrypto and trml2pdf look like they need to be build & installed. Is this so? Can i write some kind of script, that executes this installation over the web? What can i do at all if they will not write without beeing built?

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, In the past I wrote a cgi to download and build Python on hosting that only allowed ftp access.

If you know the target platform it will be easier to set up a virtual machine locally, build the files you need there and upload the compiled versions. Make sure you statically link them if the hosting is missing libraries.

The best idea might be to switch to hosting with ssh access though.

Comment: cgi is a new thing to me. Setting up freebsd virtual machine seems like something hard, as i know nothing about freebsd nor virtual machines.

I might have to switch indeed, but if you could provide the example of the cgi file you used, it would be excellent help. How can i find out if i can even use cgi files with that hosting?

Answer (score 0):

i doubt you can install only over web (e.g. what about permissions - maybe some could be set over ftp, but other not)

is it possible to ask your hosting provider to include satchmo in their services?